# Obtener referencia de un elemento XAML en código

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding

Estoy tratando de referenciar un elemento hijo de un `ListView` para poder ocupar su contenido dentro de una función, pero creo que estoy haciendo mal la referencia. Necesito obtener el valor de **signx** (que es el valor de la propiedad `x:Name`, elemento  hijo del `ListView` que necesito), la cuestión es que su contenido lo estoy obteniendo de un binding.

¿Alguien podría decirme qué estoy haciendo mal o si hay alguna forma más propia de hacer lo que necesito?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Conapesca_Manager.UserInfo">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
      <ListView x:Name="listMembers" CachingStrategy="RetainElement" ItemTapped="OnSelected" Margin="0,10,0,0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout Spacing="4" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Text="Usuario: " FontSize="16" />
                  <Label x:Name="firstName" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Red" />
                  <Label Text="Roll: " FontSize="16" />
                  <Label x:Name="rol" Text="{Binding Roll}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Red" />
                  <Label x:Name="signx" Text="{Binding Firma}" IsVisible="True" />
                </StackLayout>
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>

      <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="False" x:Name="Cator" />
      <Image x:Name="Imgx" IsVisible="False" />
      <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin GeoLocator!" x:Name="testx" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
      <ActivityIndicator x:Name="waitActIndicator" />
      <Label x:Name="res_x" />

      <Label Margin="0,5,0,0" Text="Datos de usuario" />
      <Button Margin="0,5,0,5" Clicked="DeleteUserInfo" Text="Eliminar datos de usuario" />
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Código dentro del XAML.cs:

```
public void ToImage() {
  Cator.IsRunning = true;
  Imgx.IsVisible = true;

  var img64 = signx.Text;
  //MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(img64));
  // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(img64);
  // Convert byte[] to Image
  Image image = new Image();

  Imgx.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
  Cator.IsRunning = false;
}
```

Tambien encontré algo así:

```
public void ToImage() {
  Cator.IsRunning = true;
  Imgx.IsVisible = true;

  foreach (ListViewItem item in listMembers.ItemsSource)
  {
    Label mylabel = (Label)item.FindName("signx");
    var img64 = mylabel.Text;

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(img64));
    //Convert Base64 String to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(img64);
    //Convert byte[] to Image
    Xamarin.Forms.Image image = new Xamarin.Forms.Image();

    Imgx.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));

  }

  Cator.IsRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: coloca el codigo para poder ayudarte y no una imagen. desde donde llamas ToImage() ? desde algun evento del listview?

Comment: Aún no llamo a mi método, lo que me interesa es que mi **xaml.cs** encuentre a mi objeto dentro del **xaml**

Comment: El problema que tienes es que has puesto nombre a un control que está dentro de un TEMPLATE. No puedes obtener referencia a ese item sin más, porque al ser parte de un template, ese mismo template se repite con cada uno de los items. Por tanto, tienes una lista cuyo label tiene exactamente el mismo Name.

Como estás usando bindings, lo lógico es que acudas al ItemsSource del listview, localices el item que quieres editar, y le cambies su atributo Firma. Si tienes el INotifyPropertyChanged bien implementado, verás el cambio automáticamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro de tu `ContentPage`, si el metodo `ToImage` existe dentro del archivo `*.xaml.cs`, perteneciente al `*.xaml` donde se encuentra tu `Label`, entonces solo tienes que cambiar esta linea:

```
var img64 = ...;
```

Por:

```
var img64 = this.FindByName<Label>("signx").Text;
```

Con eso ya debes poder obtener el valor de la propiedad `Text` en el `Label` con nombre `"signx"`.

#### Luego de indagar un poco más:

El problema no era exactamente como obtener la referencia de un objeto, sino como acceder al enlace de datos que estaba debajo de los elementos de `ListView`, en el caso del op *(vease [este chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74997/discussion-between-nacl-and-e-rawrdriguez-ophanim))*, intentaba acceder a un elemento que era parte de una colección, entonces, simplemente le dije que hiciera un cast a `List<T>` de la clase `Miembro` *(Explicado en el chat)*, al final quedamos con el siguiente código:

```
var TmpList = (List<Member>)listMembers.ItemsSource; 
var img64 = (TmpList != null && TmpList.Count > 0) ? TmpList[0].Firma : ""; 
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(img64); 

Xamarin.Forms.Image image = new Xamarin.Forms.Image(); 
Imgx.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
```

- Referencia: [`T FindByName<T>(Element, string)`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName%7BT%7D/p/Xamarin.Forms.Element/System.String/)

Comment: Me da System.NullRefereceException:Object reference not set on an instance if an object - justo en esa linea cuando lo corro

Comment: pues cuando corro la función ya existe y contiene datos **signx** pero  estaba pensando que quizá no puede encontrarlo porque es parte de un **listview** no crees que pueda de alguna manera entrar al listview y detro de el buscar a **signx** ?

Comment: Claro, con la misma función, cambias `FindByName<ListView>("nombrelistview");` y debe retornar el `ListView`.

Comment: pues ya le di el **if** y no es null, pero el error persiste

Comment: Puedes ver el valor de la propiedad `Text` del `Label` que retorna? Has intentado ver si el binding tiene algun valor?

Comment: Si mira,  <Label x:Name="signx" Text="{Binding Firma}" IsVisible="True" /> ahí es donde está y en efecto, puedo ver que tiene contenido , que firma vale un texto

Comment: Una pregunta muy sencilla ... ¿Cuantas filas tiene el listview?

Comment: Una respuesta , 1

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74997/discussion-between-nacl-and-e-rawrdriguez-ophanim).